# Customize PDF Render from datatables PDF Export

Tags: laravel, datatable, datatables, pdfmake

I have succesfully rendered my table with `datatables`, but I'm unable to find a way to customize the downloaded PDF file to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWYty.png). I was wondering if I could use pdfmake and add it to the buttons option.
PS :

- the data is rendered through ajax

Thanks in advance .